# (Un-)Commenting-shortcut for MetaEditor on PC & Mac

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mql5, metatrader5

The shortcut for **commenting** (whole blocks of) code in MetaEditor is "**Ctrl + '** " (both on PC and Mac).

However, the PC-shortcut for **uncommenting** is "**Ctrl + ;**" while the same doesn't work on Mac.

Does anybody know the shortcut for uncommenting (blocks of) code on **Mac**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution myself: at least on the Austrian/German keyboard layout it's "Ctrl + ö"